# how to debug a corrupted video file with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

for example I downloaded some film, it is somehow encoded with some program, when I try to use ffmpeg to convert it, let's say from mkv to mp4, i get an error that:

```
[matroska,webm @ 0x1d06640] Read error at pos. 2241497 (0x2233d9)
```

now how can I know where is the reason that this happens? should just avoid this kind of files, or somehow debug it and see what is the reason behind this error? or maybe skip this error frames, but i dont know how many frames may be like this, what if most of the file is filled with corrupted frames, altough it is playable in the video player

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post online one of these problem files?